# Centering and floating within the same container

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position, centering

I have one container having some content centered in but I want to put something on the left and I am having trouble figuring out how to do this.

Is the only way to do this with `absolute` positioning? Here is the code I have been playing around with to show ads an example:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <p class="one">Left</p>
  <p style="clear: both;"></p>
  <div class="center">Center</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;
}

.container .one {
  float: left;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.clearfix:after,
.clearfix:before
{
  display: table;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
}

.container .center {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
}
```

**CodePen:**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqeBNp

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/zmxgd8ea/

Comment: Hmmm yeah I guess so. I think I got tied up with trying to clear the float after the first element that I forgot I didn't really need to and could just apply a clearfix to the container to take care of it afterwards.

Comment: @Vitorinofernandes Just did some more testing on this and it actually doesn't work how I wanted; if the text is long on the left side for example you will notice the centered text will center itself within the remaining available space rather than be centered within the containers whole width.

Answer (score 0):

Try applying `display:inline-block` and `float:left` with some `width` of both the div.

```css
.container {
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: auto;
}
.container .one {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  background-color: aqua;
}
.container .center {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="one">Left</div>
  <div class="center">Center</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but didn't really wanna restrict the widths of the elements.

Answer (score -1):

You should use Flexbox, it is very easy to use. Let me know if this is what you were looking for?

Screenshot:

[image]

Live instance of the code --> https://jsfiddle.net/7fo5ceb6/

//HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">    
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div>left</div>
    <div>center</div>
    <div>right</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

//CSS

```
body{
    margin: 0 !important;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

#container{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;

    background: #5c5c5c;
}
#container>div{
    padding: 10px 0px;
    text-align: center;

    -webkit-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;

    -webkit-align-self: center;
    align-self: center;

    margin: 5px;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Only problem is `IE9` doesn't support it and `IE10` only supports the *2012* version, whatever that means.

Comment: @Brett I did compatibility testing on IE recently and the code above will work just fine, however IE still hasn't built support "align-items" and won't display properly even in IE 11 smh...

Comment: Hmm ok. So which IE versions did you test the above with?

Comment: @Brett I'm sorry your right about IE9 but IE10 works fine except for the "align-items" and "flex-wrap" and such... such a horrible browser isn't it?

Comment: It sure is haha...... I'd be ok not supporting `IE8`, but need to still support `IE9` unfortunately.